# Field Calculator Expression Assistance - Return Value Based on a Text String in Another Field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm still in my infancy learning Python (also using arcpy), and I've got a field calculator expression that I am having trouble formatting. Hoping someone can help... I am using ArcMap 10.5.

I am trying to have a calculation return a value of "1" if a specific word is found in another cell (text string). So for example... A cell named "BODY_PART" contains the following string "BACK ARM LEG", I would need the expression to return a value of "1" into a new/blank field (already created) based on looking for the word "ARM".... In my mind, the equation would look something like this: If "BODYPARTS" contains "ARM" print "1" else print "0"(wrong syntax, I know).

Here is how far I got...

**in the Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
def findWholeWord(leg) :
  if 'LEG' in !BODYPARTS! :
    print('1')
  else :
    print('0')
```

This is giving me a Syntax error on Line 2.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You run the field calculator on the field you want to update, eg `LEG` and in your expression you specify the field you want to query with your function eg `BODYPARTS`.

I would also include an `.upper()` to force it to find all case variances like `LEG`, `leg`, `Leg`, etc.

Instead of `print` use `return` to have it write back to the field in your attribute table.

Pre-logic script code:

```
def findWholeWord(bodyparts):
  if 'LEG' in bodyparts.upper():
    return 1
  else:
    return 0
```

Expression:

```
findWholeWord(!BODYPARTS!)
```

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! I just tested this and it worked perfectly!